# min-width em using media query

Tags: html, css

I am learning how to work with CSS using EM. (I am used to always using px)

I saw the following media query

```
@media screen and (min-width: 50em){

}
```

I was just wondering what is the 50em relative to?

When I was reading about EM it specifies that Em is Relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)

But with min-width there is no font size?? I am a bit confused here.. any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: this may help get your head around calculating it http://pxtoem.com/ . this is also a great article to use px, rem , and em to scale nicely. https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the `50em` is referencing the base font size, which is (for most browsers) **16px**. It can be configured by the users pre-defined preferences within the browser.

Some browsers will either set the root `html` element (which `rem` is based upon) to be **16px** or a percentage of the base font size as defined above.